# How to update ComboBox while performing button action in another tab in java

Tags: java, jcombobox, jtabbedpane

I have a JTabbedPane with two panels inside: panel1 and panel2. I want to update my JComboBox which is located in panel2 when performing an action in panel1.

In panel1 I have this code:

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
tabbedPane.addTab("panel1", null, panel1, null);
panel1.setLayout(null);

//some code

JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    

        // ?
    }
});
btnSubmit.setBounds(12, 155, 150, 25);
panel1.add(btnSubmit);
```

In panel2 is my JComboBox:

```
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
tabbedPane.addTab("panel2", null, panel2, null);
panel2.setLayout(null);
//some code
final JComboBox comboBox_2 = new JComboBox();
comboBox_2.setBounds(12, 240, 200, 24);
panel2.add(comboBox_2);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You need a reference to the comboBox in the tabbed pane

Comment: @MadProgrammer I formulated my question wrong the first time. Can you please take a look again? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty implementation.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class Window extends JFrame {

    JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2= new JPanel();
    JComboBox<String> comboBox_2 = new JComboBox<String>();

    ActionListener buttonListener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            comboBox_2.addItem("abc");
            comboBox_2.addItem("def");

        }
    };


    public Window() {

        initP1();
        initP2();
        initJTP();

    }

    public void initJTP(){
        jtp.add(panel1);
        jtp.add(panel2);
        this.add(jtp);
    }

    public void initP1(){
         JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
         btnSubmit.setBounds(12, 155, 150, 25);
         btnSubmit.addActionListener(buttonListener);
         panel1.add(btnSubmit);
    }


    public void initP2(){
        comboBox_2.setBounds(12, 240, 200, 24);
        panel2.add(comboBox_2);

    }


       /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        Window frame = new Window();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: This works, thank you. But now the names of the tabs wont show.

Comment: you will want to add the panel names back into the jtp.add() calls like you had before.  jtp.add("somename", panel1);